# What key to use if adding a data template to the resources of a control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplate

I have a data template that is defined in a XAML file. The root of the XAML is **not** a resource dictionary but the data template itself. Now I want to add this data template to the resources of a control. Unfortunately, I don't know what key to use.

```
myControl.Resources.Add(???, dataTemplate);
```

Although I use the data templates DataType property (i.e. the type that I want to template) the WPF resource lookup engine does not use my data template.

Anyone? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I know that with styles the type of the target would do the trick but with data templates this seems to be different...

**EDIT:**

Answer: Ok, I did a little bit of debugging. Here is the correct code

```
myControl.Resources.Add(new DataTemplateKey(typeof(...)), dataTemplate);
```

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what was put in the answers.  Why not accept one?

Comment: Err,... no, the answers are wrong. They omit the creation of a DataTemplateKey instance.

Answer (score 0):

use as key the type for which the datatemplate is designed like:
myControl.Resources.Add(typeof(TheType), dataTemplate);

Answer (score 0):

Actually Moser is right,

DataTemplates work on data objects.. ControlTemplates are for well.. controls...
If your DataTemplate is for, lets say Car objects, use Mosers example like so:

```
myControl.Resources.Add(typeof(Car), dataTemplate);
```

Set your Car object on DataContext of the control that needs to use this DataTemplate, et voila :)

---

Or you could always make up your own key:

```
myControl.Resources.Add("MyAwesomeDataTemplate", dataTemplate);
```

And then set the Template property like so:

```
Template="{StaticResource MyAwesomeDataTemplate}"
```